# how to keep session data when redirect to external url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, session, laravel-passport

I am new on PHP. I have a laravel api and laravel webui in different servers. When i make a request for login in webui, sent it to api and if result is success return laravel/passport token to webui. I stored token in session(in webui auth controller).

AuthController;

```
Session::put('token', $value['token']);
```

My CustomAuth Middleware;

```
    class CustomAuth extends Middleware {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null){
            if (Session::has('token')) {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return response(view('pages.unauthorized'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Payment method;

```
return redirect()->away($redirectUrl);
```

And then, when payment is success/fail wirecard returning to my site(callbackUrl). In this section, session data is lost and user redirect to login page. I am not sure whether I am wrong in the auth part or use the session incorrectly. Can i store session data when i redirect? Or how can i change auth part?

Note: success and fail routes has to be in auth middleware. And my all routes in web middleware group. In app/Http/Kernel.php, this line added in 'web'

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally when you are building an API, we are not using `web` middleware group but `api` middleware group. Thus if all your routes are in `api.php`(they should be here) then the session is not activated or it won't work because you are using `api` middleware group and `api` guard here.

Another thing is, you have already generated a token using `passport` so you don't need to store the token in `session`. That's the awesome thing about Json Web Token. It can be parsed when your **WebUI** pass the token back to backend. The backend/API can just look at it and see if the token is authenticated, no need to check session or anything like that when you are handling token. To do so you have to pass through `auth:api` middleware for your api routes.

Lastly, you have to make sure that the **WebUI** is sending back the token in correct form(e.g. Bearer header, basic auth etc.).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for your answer. My webui routes in web middleware not in API. And i don't use session in API, i store token in webui. But when i redirect to external payment page and then returning my site, session data is lost. Not just only token, i store shopping cart in session also. I losing everything.

Comment: I know this problem you faced is old. But currently I have the exact same problem, If you have a solution can you please share @gurcansbr

Comment: The solution is here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/session-getting-destroyed-after-payment-gateway-redirecting-to-success-callback-url?page=1&replyId=666988
But this solution not worked for me. And then I create a table in db for save the user information before start payment process and I created a unique ID for payment. Then I gave this ID to my callback url. When payment gateway returning to my callback url, I got my ID and go to db. I fetched my payment and user information from db and then logged in user. The last ting I deleted user information in table @JoyRamSenGupta

Comment: @gurcansbr I have done it quite similarly. I pass in my user id to the payment gateway in the post variable. When I return from the gateway I receive the same post variables by design of the PGW. I can use this user ID to login. However, This does not login to the same session, a new session is created. Although I am doubtful about the security of doing this! Is this the right way to do it ? Is there any more secure and recommended approach to handling such requests?

Answer (score 0):

**One possible solution:**
when working with payment callback you should always remember the session data for addreses including https, http,  www and none-www are different. 
You should always always force (www or none-www) and (https or http). in this way you can always be sure that user will always come back to the address that user session data is stored.

according to web server you are using, the approach to do this will be different.

for example if you are using apache, you can use following config in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # remove wwww.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

    # redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You saying, if session data is in http://www.example.com and then callback url it has to be http://www.example.com format. Because user's session data stored in this url. Am i right? If i get it right, this not worked. I checked this and result still same